# how to connect button with next screen on android studio

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I am building this application on android studio and i am trying to link my button with next activity which is login screen. before i had it working with register screen but then i messed up with code now it just doesn't work when i run the application and click on register button my app crashes and shuts down and login button doesn't even do anything. 
below is the code for main page activity and login page activity
first i will paste frontpage activity code where the button is, then its java class, then i will paste loginpage activity and then its java class. 
can someone pls advice me how to call the login activity from the login button on the front page.
thank you so much in advance

frontpage activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Login">

<LinearLayout

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="@drawable/bg3"
        android:gravity="center|top">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Easy Booking"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="33dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#0c0c0c"
        />

    <Button

        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/btLogin"
        android:onClick="bLogin"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Register"
        android:id="@+id/btRegister"
        android:onClick="bRegister"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

now its java class

```
public class Frontpage extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_frontpage);
    //OnclickButtonListener();
}
public void bLogin(View view) {

}
public void onButtonClick(View v){

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btRegister) {
        Intent i = new Intent(new Intent(Frontpage.this, Register.class));
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
/**
public void OnclickButtonListener(){
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
    button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new       Intent("/Users/umairfarooq/AndroidStudioProjects/Easybooking/app/src/main/res/layo      ut/activity_register");
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
    );
} /**@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity_login, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
*/}
```

below is the login activity

```
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"                tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#635b5b"
android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login Form"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:id="@+id/etUsername"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="userLogin"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register Now"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:onClick="userReg"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

and now login java class

```
package com.example.umairfarooq.easybooking;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}
public void buttonOnClick (View v){
}
}
```

Comment: excellent! all of you guys are amazing. can't explain how much you guys are helping me. many thanks to Titus and Swagata Acharyya

Comment: If an answer helped you in any way, please vote it up. If an answer solves your problem, then 'accept' that answer as the correct one. You will see a 'check mark' symbol below the vote up/down arrows.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your activities don't contain the methods that you've set for your buttons' `android:onClick` attribute.

For the layout that the `Frontpage` activity is using, you can either change `btRegister` button's `android:onClick` attribute to `android:onClick="onButtonClick"` or create a `public void bRegister(View v){...}` method in that activity.

For the `Login` activity, the layout has two buttons with their `android:onClick` attribute set to `userReg` and `userLogin`, you can either create those methods in the activity or change both of those attributes values to `buttonOnClick`.

Answer (score 1):

> when i run the application and click on register button my app crashes
>   and shuts down

It is because this button:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="108dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Register"
    android:id="@+id/btRegister"
    android:onClick="bRegister"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

in your frontpage activity needs a method with signature `public void bRegister(View view)` in your FrontPage.java class. As you do not have this method, it crashes.

> login button doesn't even do anything

The reason is, this button

```
<Button

    android:layout_width="98dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/btLogin"
    android:onClick="bLogin"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

in your frontpage activity needs a method called `public void bLogin(View view)` in your Frontpage.java class. Though the method is present, you do not have any code in it, hence it does not do anything.

You need to add proper code in bLogin method so that your login button starts functioning, and even before that add a bRegister method so that your register button starts working.

Hope this helps you.